# RemoveExtendedProperty throws error when used on an occurrence of a recurring appointment

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, recurring, ews-managed-api

I am developing an application that syncs an exchange calendar to another calendar. I put extended properties on the exchange appointments in order to preserve the mapping between appointments in the two calendars.  Everything is working fine until I try to remove an extended property from an occurrence of a recurring appointment.  When I try doing this, I get the error:

```
The delete action is not supported for this property.
```

Here is a code snippet that demonstrates the error:

```
public void ExchangeTest()
{
    ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1)
    {
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain")
    };
    service.AutodiscoverUrl("username@domain.com");

    Appointment appt = new Appointment(service)
    {
        Recurrence = new Recurrence.DailyPattern(DateTime.Now, 2) { NumberOfOccurrences = 3},
        Start = DateTime.Now,
        End = DateTime.Now.AddHours(2),
        Subject = "Test Appointment"
    };
    NameResolutionCollection resolutionCollection = service.ResolveName("username", ResolveNameSearchLocation.DirectoryOnly, false);
    string mailboxAddress = resolutionCollection.First().Mailbox.Address;
    FolderId folderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, mailboxAddress);
    appt.Save(folderId);
    PropertySet properties = new PropertySet(AppointmentSchema.ICalUid);
    appt.Load(properties);

    CalendarView view = new CalendarView(DateTime.Today, DateTime.Today.AddDays(8)){PropertySet = properties};

    IEnumerable<Appointment> occurrences = service.FindAppointments(folderId, view)
        .Where(a => a.ICalUid == appt.ICalUid);

    ExtendedPropertyDefinition definition = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.PublicStrings, "TestProperty", MapiPropertyType.String);
    Appointment firstOccurrence = occurrences.First();
    firstOccurrence.SetExtendedProperty(definition, "test");
    firstOccurrence.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AutoResolve);

    //The error occurs on the next line.
    firstOccurrence.RemoveExtendedProperty(definition);
    firstOccurrence.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AutoResolve);

    //clean up
    appt.Delete(DeleteMode.HardDelete);
}
```

It appears that the error is only thrown for an Exchange 2007 server (It works on 2010). Am I doing something wrong, or is this a problem with Exchange?  Is there a way to work around this issue?  Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up not using the **RemoveExtendedProperty** function.  Instead, I worked around it by just setting the property again, but setting it to an empty space.  I then handled the empty space in code.  This appears to be a problem with Exchange or the managed API.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try;

```
appointment.Delete(DeleteMode.SoftDelete,SendCancellationsMode.SendToAllAndSaveCopy);
```

Comment: I don't want to delete the appointment.  I want to remove the extended property from the appointment.